# I wrote the procedure, only one column is filled in, tell me where the error is?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I tried to write a procedure that fills the table with random data using the pseudo-random sequence formula, only one column is filled, help find my error, here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_zakaz2(Номер integer, Сумма integer)
AS
$$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Заказ(Номер, Сумма)
SELECT Заказ(Номер, Сумма) FROM generate_series(1, 100000), i WHERE
result = next * 1103515245+12345;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0xUX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sALwA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
INSERT INTO Заказ(Номер, Сумма)
    SELECT i,  (next * 1103515245+12345) % 101
    FROM generate_series(1, 100000) gs(i)
    END;
```

Note that `%101` which is normally used in this case.  This limits the result to some finite range -- in this case 0 to 100.  Also, the two numbers used would typically be prime (or at least relatively prime) -- and numbers ending in 5 are not.